# How to configure Netflix Turbine to use basic auth when collecting data from Hystrix streams?

Tags: basic-authentication, hystrix, turbine

We're exposing Hystrix streams from severals services. These streams are exposed from the management port of each service which is protected by basic authentication. Is it possible to configure Turbine to use basic auth when contacting to (certain) Hystrix streams and if so how?

Comment: I am using turbine webapp. Is any sort of authentication possible in it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a turbine webapp. Do you mean the hystrix dashboard?

Comment: there are two ways to add turbine. One is by adding their jar and second is using the war instead. I am using the war

Comment: could you provide some info on how it works

Comment: I'm just connecting to turbine from the hystrix dashboard. Then turbine takes care of connecting to all the individual hystrix streams. I've created my own turbine discovery extension that connects to pods in Kubernetes with certain labels. This is proprietary though.

Comment: have you imported the turbine jar in your web app or have you used the turbine war? Also how -streams "http://johan:password@mydomain.org" works? where have you given the actual username and password to get authenticated? Are you giving them through any config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/Netflix/Turbine/pull/93) to Turbine that allows you to specify basic auth as a part of the URI. For example `http://username:password@mydomain.org`.